# MacOS Monterey 12.4 keeps changing spaces order despite having the setting off

Tags: monterey, spaces, mission-control, apple-silicon

I have macOS Monterey 12.4 on a new M1 MacBook Air. Currently, I regularly find my spaces to be mixed up. This is annoying since I then have to stop what I am doing and fix them up in Mission Control. In addition, I find that every time this happens and I re-open Firefox, I lose access to any minimized windows, as it seems that Firefox is trying to open them in a nonexistant space. Obviously, I do not want to lose my open tabs, and I switched to Firefox partially to prevent this from happening (as Safari seems to get more and more flaky every year).

I have uploaded a screenshot showing that the setting is, in fact, disabled. I have tried toggling it, restarting, etc. and it continues to incorrectly behave.

[image: System Preferences > Mission Control]

Comment: Are any of these fullscreen Spaces? Basically fullscreen breaks Spaces, because each new Space is simply added to the right of the last. On quit/relaunch, the order is going to be pretty random. Also, Spaces was never designed to differentiate one app over more than one Space.

Comment: @Tetsujin no, I don't use any full-screen apps. Not sure what you mean by "differentiate one app over more than one space"

Comment: One app can only be in one Space. If you have different windows in different Spaces, you confuse the system.

Comment: @Tetsujin that's simply not true. I can have finder windows open in each space. Ditto for Terminal, Safari, Firefox, QuickTime, etc.

Comment: Reboot & look again. I didn't say you couldn't force it to, I said it confuses the system.

Comment: @Tetsujin I don't understand how it would "confuse the system." I've been doing it for years, Apple clearly intends for this to be a supported option, as I can easily move windows to different spaces or open new windows in various spaces. I'm not "forcing" anything, I'm just using Space just like any other user. I can reboot however many times you want, the order continue to get messed up.

Comment: It has never been a supported option. It's changed very slightly over the years, but if you open windows from a single app across multiple Spaces then reboot, they will gather in one Space. In recent OSes this has become less rigid, but it is still not robust.

Comment: @Tetsujin I think you may be confused. I do not have "Re-open windows when logging back in" enabled. My remarks about Firefox are due to some kind of Firefox-specific feature. Back when I used Safari, all the windows would open in whichever space I opened Safari in, I'm well aware of how it normally works. It just seems as if Firefox has implemented some way of "fixing" this quirk. To note, the Firefox-specific feature worked fine in previous macOS versions, where the Spaces would not auto-rearrange against my preferences.

Comment: This has not been fixed yet. I hate this behaviour. Safari and Brave can both open windows in different spaces after restart. Just Firefox cannot. Do you know a gecko based browser that can handle this? I need Webkit, Blink (Chromium) and Gecko browsers to test the web.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue resolved itself after a few weeks, or maybe a software update. I'm not really sure, it just stopped happening and I forgot about it.